# extract word from file using sed

Tags: regex, linux, bash, sed

I have a problem when I use **sed** to extract keyword from a file.
Content in a file is like:

```
======================= keyword begin =======================
blablabla
======================== keyword end ========================
```

Then I do:

```
$ sed -n 's/=* \(.*\) begin =*/\1/p' test
keyword   ## It is ok
$ a=`sed -n 's/=* \(.*\) begin =*/\1/p' test`
$ echo "[$a]"
]keyword  ## Why the output is like this? I think it should be [keyword]
```

I just don't know why ']keyword' appear.

Comment: Can't reproduce.  What platform are you on?  What version of Bash?  It prints `[keyword]` for me, as it should.

Comment: It seems all okay, please check your version of Bash as suggested by @JohnZwinck

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This happens because your file has carriage returns, due to being created on a Windows machine. Remove them from the file with `dos2unix` or `tr -d '\r'`.

You can tell because the `\r` causes the terminal to start overwriting the same line from the beginning. If you write `[keyword` and then from the start of the line overwrite with `]`, you end up with `]keyword`.

See the [bash tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/info) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

Just change your `sed` command to:

```
a=$(sed -n 's/=* \(.*\) begin =*.*$/\1/p' file)
echo "[$a]"
[keyword]
```

This `sed` will match all `=` after `begin` and all the remaining characters after end of `=` (including `\r`).

Answer (score 0):

Use echo $a instead of echo "[$a]", It will print just keyword

If you use echo "[$a]" it will print [keyword]